# Computing similarity measure

Tags: java, wordnet

I'm using JWNL and to compute similarity measure between Strings according to wordnet, I run this code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import net.didion.jwnl.JWNL;
import shef.nlp.wordnet.similarity.SimilarityInfo;
import shef.nlp.wordnet.similarity.SimilarityMeasure;

public class wordnet
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{
    //Initialize WordNet - this must be done before you try
    //and create a similarity measure otherwise nasty things
    //might happen!
    JWNL.initialize(new FileInputStream("test/wordnet.xml"));

    //Create a map to hold the similarity config params
    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();

    //the simType parameter is the class name of the measure to use
    params.put("simType","shef.nlp.wordnet.similarity.JCn");

    //this param should be the URL to an infocontent file (if required
    //by the similarity measure being loaded)
    params.put("infocontent","file:test/ic-bnc-resnik-add1.dat");

    //this param should be the URL to a mapping file if the
    //user needs to make synset mappings
    params.put("mapping","file:test/domain_independent.txt");

    //create the similarity measure
    SimilarityMeasure sim = SimilarityMeasure.newInstance(params);


    //get a similarity that involves a mapping
    SimilarityInfo d=sim.getSimilarity("english", "english");
    System.out.println(d.getSynset1());
    System.out.println(d.getSynset2());
    System.out.println(d.getSimilarity());
    System.out.println(d);

}

}
```

but I dont know why the result is zero?!

the result is:

> Jan 27, 2013 7:03:00 PM net.didion.jwnl.util.MessageLog doLog
>   INFO: Installing dictionary net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.FileBackedDictionary@48fbc0
>   [Synset: [Offset: 6074471] [POS: noun] Words: English -- (the discipline that studies the English language and literature)]
>   [Synset: [Offset: 6074471] [POS: noun] Words: English -- (the discipline that studies the English language and literature)]
>   0.0
>   english#n#3  english#n#3  0.0

Could you please help me?

Comment: i dont think the synsets have equivalence relations - you should try two different words with the same meaning - as opposed to two of the same word.

Comment: @Randy: I tested it for several synonym words, but always the result is zero!

Answer (score 1):

you have to be sure to use the coressponding WordNet dictionary try Wordnet 2.0 
otherwise try WS4J for using similarity measures between sysnsets which has Wordnet 3.0 embedded